# Logging user actions in Firebase JS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to log the following user actions on my Firebase app:

- sign in/out
- page in/out
- timestamp of action

Right now, I use my own function to log actions to the database location "root > user-logs > [user's id]".
Each action is logged as 
[time in milliseconds] : [action]

These logs put a lot of data in my database.
However, I won't be accessing data stored at the user-logs locations, so my belief is that this won't lower the speed of read operations at other locations in the database.

- Question 1: Is the above belief true?
- Question 2: Is there a better way to log customized user actions?

I first thought of creating a csv file in Cloud Storage and appending user actions to the file, but then realized that in order to write to a csv file, I would first have to download it, so I decided that writing to the database would be much faster (and easier).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you write data to a location that you don't read any data from, then that write operation will not affect operations that read data from somewhere else in your database.

But storing data that you're never going to read is unlikely. Otherwise there probably wouldn't be a reason to store it. More likely you're going to want to read/query this data at some point.

Given the append-only, every-growing nature of your log data, it is unlikely that Firebase will offer the query capabilities that you need at that point. Therefor I'd recommend storing your data in a system that is more tailored towards the use-case: storing lots of data and querying that. A perfect example of such a system is Google's BigQuery.

A common way to get the data into BigQuery is to keep doing what you do now from the client: write it into the database. Then create a Cloud Function that triggers on incoming log data from your database, writes that data to BigQuery, and then deletes it from the database.

With this approach you're only using the Firebase Database for transient storage, and do the heavy lifting in BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

From the log data, I want to know: 
- how much of the users visit the app again
- how long users stay on a certain page

Comment: , what percentage of the users visits the app again after their initial user, how much time user spends on the app per visit, etc.
I was planning to store data in the database, download the JSON for all user logs, and then analyze.

I should have mentioned in my question, but with this usage in mind, would you still recommend BigQuery?

Also, would adding Cloud Function to my page make it slower?